# Jmeter Throughput significance

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, throughput

I found many post regarding jmeter throughput but I was not able to find out one thing.
What value of throughput is considered good. Say for example, for a partucular request throughput is 0.603882967 per second and for the same request (with some code changes) throughput is 0.457368667 per second

Which one is better(lower value or higher). Why ?

Answer (score 3):

Throughput is how many requests you can **put through** in a second.

The longer each request takes, the lower the throughput.

We want requests to be fast (small numbers for response time), and throughput to be high.

Looks like your code changes made it worse :-(

Answer (score 2):

JMeter's "Throughput" metric stands for "requests per amount of time". **The higher is better**, as the main goal of performance testing is to measure how many requests per time frame application under test can serve.

Throughput formula is `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

For more information refer to the following resources:

- [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports)

Comment: `the main goal of performance testing is to measure how many requests per time frame` Not necessarily